# Filter jquery datatable rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on this table that needs to filter the rows if the column has no data. I'm able to filter out the whole table but I'm having trouble filtering  out the rows for a specific columns. Any help would be much appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/mleitao/twg0qqq2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#camera').click(function() {
    $("#table-ActiveRooms tr td").each(function() {
        var cell = $(this)
        if (cell.children().length == 0) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
});

$('#btnReset').click(function() {
    $("#table-ActiveRooms tr").each(function() {
        $(this).show();
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of the suggestions you're getting are over-complicated. You don't need to use `.each`, nor do you need `if` statements to check for empty values.

By modifying your selectors to be a bit more specific, your code can be much cleaner and more efficient, without using a single `each` or `if`.

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/twg0qqq2/44/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $tableRows = $("#table-ActiveRooms tr");

    $('#camera').click(function() {
         $tableRows.has("td:nth-child(2):empty").hide();
    });

    $('#monitor').click(function() {
         $tableRows.has("td:nth-child(3):empty").hide();
    });

    $('#phone').click(function() {
         $tableRows.has("td:nth-child(4):empty").hide();
    });

    $('#btnReset').click(function() {
         $tableRows.show();
    });
});
```

The 2 in `nth-child(2)` represents column 2. As you can assume, we simply change this number to match for `monitor` and `phone`.

Comment: I like your answer here, I think it is a little cleaner and easier to read. thanks I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select specifically the `td` corresponding to your selected filter for it to work. In your code, you hide the `tr` when any of the `td` in the line is empty.

You can add a class to identify these td, like ih this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ttk2dy3f/2/

edit: sorry i had forgotten to save the fiddle, done now

Comment: Thanks for the simple fix! Much appreciated

Comment: This can be done without using classes, `.each` loops, if statements, etc. For sake of efficiency and readability, I'd highly suggest taking a peak at my answer. Otherwise, if this is the solution you've chosen, make sure to accept it.

Comment: Totally correct Santi, considering the level of the question, i prefered explain hiw what was wrong simply, to go step by step. If you want to downvote do as you like, not here for rep ;)

Comment: Your answer is not incorrect and you answered the question, so I certainly have no reason to down-vote. I just feel obligated to point this out so that OP gets the best solution available to him/her.

Answer (score -1):

This will filter based on a drop down, you can apply it to your code. data[1] is the column you want to filter.

```
 var employeeName = '';

        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
            if (data[1].indexOf(employeeName) > -1) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    );



    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#employeeSelection').change(function (event) {
                        employeeName = $('#employeeSelection').val();

                        table.draw();
                    });

var table = $('#mainGrid').DataTable({
                paging: false,
                ordering: true,
                aaSorting: [],
                scrollX: true,
                searching: true,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'print'
                ]
            });

         });
```